# How do I unlock Kingdoms that I can't even see?

Tags: gems-of-war

How do I unlock Kingdoms that I can't even see?

Like, Silverglade, Bright Forest and Shentang?

When I click things that need me to finish those kingdoms, like the Soulforge, and have them tell me where to go, they seem to point me to a kingdom-less wilderness.

Do I have to finish all the other Kingdoms to even see the rest?

I already have Sword's Edge and Pridelands, but I can't see Merlantis, Silverglade, or Urskaya either.

Where Shentang and Bright Forest are supposed to be:

[image]

Official Annotated World Map:

[image]

Comment: Screenshot would be helpful to see how *"kingdom-less wilderness"* looks like. How far are you into a game? I recall there was some intro quests which locks you to a specific kingdom until you complete it.

Comment: @Sinatr - Sorry that the pictures are so big... Do you know how to shrink them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 4.5 [introduced a new kingdom progression system](https://community.gemsofwar.com/t/4-5-update-patch-notes/57370). Rather than being able to unlock kingdoms at will, kingdoms are organised into 10 groups, and only by completing the questlines of all kingdoms in a group, will the next group be unlocked.

Here's the groupings:

[image: Kingdom grouping table]